# How to setup private deps from github in rebar.config?

Tags: erlang, github, rebar

Just wondering if it is possible to setup private deps in rebar.config? Especially if this deps from github.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is fixed. I had wrong envs in iTerm somehow.

Comment: Please post solution and mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution, all you have to do it to specify git (not https) of the dep you want to use. Then execute `./rebar get-deps` and you good to go.

Important: if you use iTerm and it doesn't work for you - Terminal.app is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite solution, I was using `git://` and it didn't work so I switched to `https://`.

Original: `{PACKAGE_NAME, {git, "git://github.com/ORG/PRIVATE_REPO.git", {branch, "MY_BRANCH"}}}`

Working: `{PACKAGE_NAME, {git, "https://github.com/ORG/PRIVATE_REPO", {branch, "MY_BRANCH"}}}`

Both `rebar3 compile` and `rebar3 shell` now work fine. This is on macOS Mojave v10.14.2, Terminal v2.9.1, rebar3 v3.8.0, Erlang/OTP 21, ERTS 10.2.3. I'm using locally stored Github credentials specifically a Personal Access Token because I have to use 2FA for work.